# When connecting veins and sumo, will the ".py" file created as TraCI not be reflected in veins?

Tags: python, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am planning to conduct an experiment using an automated driving simulator.
The tool I am using is

sumo (1.8.0)
veins (5.1)
omnet++ (5.6.2)

I have completed all the installation and can run the tutorials for sumo and omnet++.

Now I'm thinking of changing the behavior of the vehicle and implementing inter-vehicle communication.

For this purpose, I found a python program called traci and created a simple one.
When I ran it, sumo started up and I confirmed that the behavior of the vehicle was changed.

However, I could not get veins and sumo to work without

veins_launchd -vv -c /c/...... /sumo-gui.exe

After connecting veins and sumo with "veins_launchd -vv -c /c/ /sumo-gui.exe", when I try to run the simulator on the omnet++ side, it doesn't reflect the program I made in python.
I was only able to run the simulator before the behavior was changed.

I later understood that traci is on the sumo side and on the omnet++ side.
Is it possible that the program created in python only runs sumo?

I think it's because I don't understand the connection between the simulators, but if anyone knows, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The connection is simple. SUMO provides an interface (which is called TraCI) and your python script as well as Veins use that interface to communicate with SUMO. While it is possible that multiple external applications use that interface simultaneously (see https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/TraCI.html#multiple_clients) they both have to be adapted to do so. It is probably easy to adapt your python script, adapting Veins might be a little harder but not too hard. You could try to open a ticket here: https://github.com/sommer/veins/issues and ask for support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm sorry.
I've been stuck here for a long time, so it's possible my understanding is wrong.
So let me just confirm.
When I run the .py file in a "windows" command prompt, the xml file created by sumo is rewritten by TraCI.
The sumo file you sent me
I have also tried "--remote-port XXXX" in the sumo you sent me, but it was not recognized by either "mingwenv.cmd" or "windows command prompt".
 If you are able to use --remote-port　XXXX, you can use
Is it possible to send a .py file to veins if I run it in "windows command prompt"?

Comment: TraCI does not rewrite any XML files. It changes the simulation online by sending messages to it via a network connection. The setup you have in mind is _not_ possible without changing the source code of veins because veins currently does not support a setup where multlple clients connect to sumo because this requires a different setup procedure.

Comment: Thank you so much!

I've been struggling with the passing of my own .py files for a long time, and it's really clear to me that it's very hard to run from a .py file, and that I'm using C++ in the veins to change the behavior of the car.

From now on, I'm going to learn traci in veins!